# ERROR 500 AL SUBIR CSV A MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Tengo el siguiente fragmento en mi servidor php para subir ciertas columna de datos de un archivo csv. la subida de la extension esta controlada por javascript por lo que siempre que procese un archivo sera solo .csv, el tema es que actualmente no toma ni un valor la tabla y me arroja error 500 el servidor donde esta alojada.

Fragmento:

```
<?php
include('is_logged.php');//Archivo verifica que el usario que intenta acceder a la URL esta logueado
require_once ("../config/db.php");//Contiene las variables de configuracion para conectar a la base de datos
require_once ("../config/conexion.php");//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos
include ("../config/funciones.php");
$action = (isset($_REQUEST['action'])&& $_REQUEST['action'] !=NULL)?$_REQUEST['action']:'';

if (isset($_POST['upload_linea'])) {
    

$tipo       = $_FILES['precintos_linea']['type'];
$tamanio    = $_FILES['precintos_linea']['size'];
$archivotmp = $_FILES['precintos_linea']['tmp_name'];
$lineas     = file($archivotmp);

$i = 0;

foreach ($lineas as $linea) {
    $cantidad_registros = count($lineas);
    $cantidad_regist_agregados =  ($cantidad_registros - 1);

    if ($i != 0) {

        $datos = explode(";", $linea);
       
        $code_kit                = !empty($datos[0])  ? ($datos[0]) : '';
        $num_precinto             = !empty($datos[2])  ? ($datos[2]) : '';
        $color               = !empty($datos[4])  ? ($datos[4]) : '';
        $date_recep               = !empty($datos[13])  ? ($datos[13]) : '';
        $correlativo = num_precinto($num_precinto);
        
        
        $fechita = str_replace('/','-',$date_recep);
        $recepcion = date('Y-m-d', strtotime ($fechita));

        
          
            
       
   $insertar = "INSERT INTO precinto_linea(" 
           . "code_kit, "
           ."num_precinto, "
           ."correlativo, "
           ."color, "
            ."fecha_recepcion "
       .") VALUES("
            ."'".$code_kit."',"
            ."'".$num_precinto."',"
           ."'".$correlativo."',"
            ."'".$color."',"
            ."'".$recepcion."'"    
        .")";  
    
      $query_new_insert =  mysqli_query($con, $insertar);
        if ($query_new_insert){
            $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
            
            $message [] = "done";
        } else{
            
            $errors []= "Lo siento algo ha salido mal.".mysqli_error($con);
        }
    }

    //  echo '<div>'. $i. "). " .$linea.'</div>';
    $i++;
}
        
    

}

?>
<script language='javascript'>
function redireccionarPagina() {
window.location.href = '../precintos.php';
}
setTimeout("redireccionarPagina()", 0000);
    </script>
```

En mi localhost tampoco almacena. mi tabla tiene la siguiente estructura:

[image: ESTRUCTURA MYSQL]

Comment: Para poder visualizar que esta causando el error, asegurate de configurar PHP para que los imprima, es decir, al principio, antes de todo, agrega `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. PD: En tu caso y por las dudas, quizas sea conveniente hacerlo despues de todos los requires e includes.

Comment: no me arroja nada, me direcciona a la ruta de mi sv, pero ahi se queda. Es extraño porque venia trabajando bien, de hecho tengo algo de 1500 registros subidos desde el csv, pero ahora no sube nada y se queda en ese punto mencionado.

Comment: El status 500 indica que hubo un error en el servidor. Habría que ver el log de errores de apache a ver que reporta, pues el script no se ejecuta correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo que pruebes en php un framework para php, yo uso codeigniter 3, dejando de lado eso intenta colocar un try cash para saber que error te puede dar. aqui un ejemplo, ojala te ayude

```
try {
  echo inverso(5) . "\n";
  echo inverso(0) . "\n";
}catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Excepción capturada: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Comment: Hola, hice tal cual me comentas pero me aparece completamente en blanco, es decir no me arroja algún mensaje desde mi localhost :(

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Tu error 500 es posible que sea por uno de los dos "require_once", que no encuentre.
También puede haber un error 500 en cualquiera de los 4 includes que no los puedo comprobar.

Otra cosa que veo es que tienes campos en la BBDD que están marcados NOTNULL y no les estás mandando datos a insertar, si están en NOTNULL has de enviarles valores adecuados a cada campo.

Espero te haya sido útil.